# How should I append data in text box when user is writing

Tags: c#, search

I am new here so please go easy. I need to use a text box in `c#` which should automatically append the relevant data when user is typing something.

Comment: What do you need help with? Finding the right event to trigger your appending or do you need help with appending the text?

Comment: I need some suggestions like google search :)

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? Where should the suggested values come from?

Answer (score 2):

The standard TextBox in .NET supports AutoCompletion. There is a working example in the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// Create the list to use as the custom source.  
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                });

// Create and initialize the text box. 
var textBox = new TextBox
              {
                  AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                  AutoCompleteMode = 
                      AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                  AutoCompleteSource =
                      AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                  Location = new Point(20, 20),
                  Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                  Visible = true
              };

// Add the text box to the form.
Controls.Add(textBox);

}
```